# export array in R with every "matrix" separate in a different table

Tags: arrays, r, csv

I want to export this array in csv where every matrix of my array is exported in separate tables

```
> a <- aperm(array(1:96, dim= c(4,8,3)), c(2,1,3))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
[4,]   13   14   15   16
[5,]   17   18   19   20
[6,]   21   22   23   24
[7,]   25   26   27   28
[8,]   29   30   31   32

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   33   34   35   36
[2,]   37   38   39   40
[3,]   41   42   43   44
[4,]   45   46   47   48
[5,]   49   50   51   52
[6,]   53   54   55   56
[7,]   57   58   59   60
[8,]   61   62   63   64

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   65   66   67   68
[2,]   69   70   71   72
[3,]   73   74   75   76
[4,]   77   78   79   80
[5,]   81   82   83   84
[6,]   85   86   87   88
[7,]   89   90   91   92
[8,]   93   94   95   96
```

The result I have when using    write.csv() is a table with every matrix joint together. I want 3 different tables in my csv.

May you help me?

[image: what I want]

Comment: Could you explain what the resulting csv should look like more precisely?

Comment: if a use write.csv() I have my matrices joint from left to write without separation. I want them separate from each other

Comment: To have them organized in a descendent manner would be the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not 100% clear to me, but is this what you are trying to do?

```
a = aperm(array(1:96, dim= c(4,8,3)), c(2,1,3))

b = a[,,1]

for( i in 2:dim(a)[3])
{
  # uncomment the line below if you want no white space between tables.
  b = rbind(b, rep("",ncol(b)))
  b = rbind(b,a[,,i])
}

write.csv(b,file="test.csv",row.names = F)
```

Resulting csv:

[image]

Comment: for( i in 2:dim(a)[3]) what does it mean this part of the code?

Comment: I already added a[,,1] to the b dataframe, so now we want to add a[,,2] and a[,,3] still. the dimensions of 1 are 8x4x3, and we want to loop over the third dimension. Try `dim(a)` in your console. So it simplifies to for (i in 2:3) in this case.

Comment: your code works, but I want to use them with a data set of a different length. I need to understand it in order to use it with different data sets. I have an intuition of what you did, but I would like you to explain me

Comment: for( i in 2:dim(a)[3]) so, it means repeat 2 times over the third dimension? Sorry, I haven't learnt properly looping functions. How can I learn them?

Comment: Please see here https://www.google.nl/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/amp/. You can start by just creating a for loop that print(i) to better understand what happens. Please consider accepting my answer if it helped you, that would be great!

Comment: I can understand your code now! :) may I have another question? I have a larger dataset and I want to bind columns every three a[,,1:3]  where z<-cbind(a[,,1],a[,,2],a[,,3])...  but I want to join rows every z. zz <-rbind(z,a[,,4],a[,,5],a[,,6]), rbind(zz, a[,,7],a[,,8],a[,,9]). This pattern is fuzzy :(

Comment: You can create multiple loops, one for the first three, one for 4 to 6, etc.